# Как парсить картинки с сайта на python

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Во первых спасибо [Амин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/395220/%d0%90%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd) за то что поделился своим кодом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

num_of_page = 900
for i in range(num_of_page):
    url = 'https://3dtoday.ru/3d-models?page=' + str(i + 1)
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='threedmodels_models_list__elem__title')
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('a').get_text(strip=True)
        print(title)
```

Но появился еще один вопрос как парсить картинки с сайта и записывать в паре с текстом текстом из его блока в CSV файл?
Я пробовал искать в интернете ничего по поводу этого не нашел

Comment: картинки в csv-файл? ого. не проще ли записывать пути к картинкам?

Comment: Да я так и хотел не много не правильно сформулировал мысль